# Django models inheritance and Meta class

Tags: django, inheritance, metaclass

I have a problem with django models inheritance. This is what I have :

```
class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Container(models.Model):
    size = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    ...

class BigBox(Container):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room)
    ...

class SmallBox(Container):
    big_box = models.ForeignKey(BigBox)
    ...

class Stuff(models.Model):
    container = models.ForeignKey(Container)
    ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('container__???__name',)
```

So, with this, I'm able to put some stuff in the big box or in a small box, which is in the big box.

How can I know the type of my stuff field ´container´ in order to acces to the name of the room ? I know I can write

```
container__big_box__room__name
```

and

```
container__room__name
```

but I would like something like

```
container__get_room__name.
```

Is it possible ?

Thank you,

Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your actual quuestion about the ordering meta, my answer is: **I don't think that is possible.**

Now, some workarounds:

I would rethink your model hierarchy.
To me a box/container which can be cointained in another box/container is still a box.

Have a look at this alternative:

```
class Container(models.Model):
    size = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room)
    ...

class ContainableContainer(Container):
    parent_container = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True)
    ...

class Stuff(models.Model):
    container = models.ForeignKey(Container)
    ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('container__room__name',)
```

With this solution you don't really need a different model, they're both containers, where a *cointainer of the cointainer*  is optional. And so, you can do the ordering as you have already thought.

You would have to be careful with the room field management. You need to make each contained container room be equal with its container's room.

For example, override the save method or use a pre_save signal:

```
class ContainableContainer(Container):
        parent_container = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True)
        ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.room = self.parent_container.room
        super(ContainableContainer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**EDIT**: This is actually a tree-like hierarchy. To make it more efficient query-wise  [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/) would be a nice choice.
It allows you to obtain the root container or to iterate over the box hierarchy with more efficient queries.
I don't have any experience with it, but it really seems the best possible solution.

Comment: I don't understand how my small_box could be in a different room that her big_box, since small_box is linked to a particular big_box.

Your hierarchy is pretty cool, but, my small_box must be in a big one. And I want this to be hold by the database and not by the save method.

I hope I'm clear enough, thank you and ask me questions if you want some precision.

Alex.

Comment: @Alex Sorry. My reflexion about the different rooms was wrong. That is actually the case with my proposed hierarchy. This has the disadvantage of having redundant fields because each ContainableContainer would have a field pointing to its root cointainer's room.

Comment: No problem ;).Yes, it was my first try, and as you did it, I overrode the save method. But my internship mentor would prefer this to be handled by the database. In fact, the actual question is : is there a way to use a function in the field ordering, as for example ordering = ('box__get_room()__name',) ? I didn't find anything on this subject, so maybe it isn't. I will reconsider your method with my mentor, and maybe I will be back on monday with good news ;) Thank you for your time, have a nice day.